# Store clicks as big data

Tags: database, postgresql, bigdata

I'm working on a project where i'm going to store every click made on a specific list of items. After some research I have been in doubt of what the smartest solution would be.

My system is build on a PostgreSQL database and for know I store the clicks like this'ish:

```
id        itemId        userId        ipAdress        date
1         3             1             xx.xx.xx        01/01-2018
2         1             1             xx.xx.xx        01/01-2018
3         2             NULL          xx.xx.xx        01/01-2018
4         2             NULL          xx.xx.xx        01/01-2018
5         1             2             xx.xx.xx        01/01-2018
```

My list of items should be sorted by most clicks. Therefore the query could look something like this to get the items sorted by clicks:

```
select i1.*, count(i1.id) as totalClicks from itemClicks ic1
left join items i1 
on i1.id = ic1.itemId
group by ic1.itemId
order by totalClicks desc
```

So this works fine - at least without the dataset being huge. But at one point there might be many millions of rows in the dataset. 
[According to this article by researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281629941_Performance_evaluation_of_SQL_and_MongoDB_databases_for_big_e-commerce_data) a SQL server is much faster doing aggregations why I guess keep on storing the data in an SQL server makes sense. 
The reason why I have went with PostgreSQL (for know) is because that there is no maximum database size and it is good for massive databases as I understand.

I am both comfortable working with MySQL (MariaDB), PostgreSQL and MongoDB for that matter. What is most important is that I store the data right from the beginning without ending up with a slow system.
And the database should preferably be open source.

I hope somebody can give me some feedback and tell my if i'm either on the right track or not.

crellee

Comment: Your assumption is flawed: the article talks about two products, one is MongoDB (a NoSQL database), the other one is SQL Server - a product by Microsoft. The article does not compare a NoSQL and a SQL database, it literally compares two specific products - and therefore you can't apply this to your favorite choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are large, this query will suck in a large way.

This is not a shortcoming of PostgreSQL or any other database management system, but a consequence of the fact that sorting data has an expense of `O(n × ln(n))`.

The way out of this is to pre-aggregate the data:

Whenever a click comes in, you update a table that counts the clicks per item. This is cheap, and you can get your result instantaneously. A database trigger is the way to go!

This technique is called a *materialized view*.

Comment: You're totally right. Tried the query out on a large dataset and it took 100 secs to execute. 
I've now read about materialized view and it seems like a fine way to solve my problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have added a reference to triggers (I had forgotten that).

Comment: So you're saying that for each time I store a click in the database a trigger should go and update a row in a given table and increment the count value?

Comment: No; that's the beauty of it: the update or insert *itself* starts the trigger that then modified the materialized view. Both run in the same transaction, so the database guarantees that either both succeed or both fail, and no inconsistencies are possible!